# stopping a bash script using subprocess call

Tags: bash, subprocess

Hi  I am using `subprocess.call("sudo bash /home/pi/Desktop/switchtest.sh", shell=True)` to start a python script.  The content of `switchtest.sh` is `sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/switch1.py`. Now, using the same `subprocess` call how can I stop the python script from running? Or is there any other way of stopping this?

Comment: How would you stop the script without python being involved?

Comment: Why are you calling `sudo` twice? Once should suffice.

Comment: And why are you using Python to run a shell to run Bash to run Python?

Comment: And which Python script do you want to stop? The parent or the grand-grandchild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subprocess.call is synchronous, so it will not return until your script is finished.  you can use popen to do it async:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("sudo bash /home/pi/Desktop/switchtest.sh", shell=True)
# do something else, polling or waiting perhaps
# now kill it
p.terminate()
```

Comment: i wanted to start the other program from my main program. So, I call subprocess to start the program from one function, and stop it in another function in my main program.

Comment: @bobdxcool: In general, `p.terminate()` might kill only the immediate child process, leaving grandchildren running. See [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279) in that case.

Comment: As an additional improvement, you should omit the unnecessary and wasteful `shell=True`.